# How to add a keyword argument to a class based view success_url

Tags: django, django-views

I have a class based `UpdateView` which returns the user to the `url_name` for `company_list` after the form is valid:

```
class CompanyUpdate(UpdateView):
    model = Company
    template_name = 'companies/company_update.html'
    fields = '__all__'
    success_url = str(reverse_lazy('company_list'))
```

How can I change this to return the user to a detail view that requires a keyword argument? E.g.

```
success_url = reverse_lazy('company_detail', kwargs={'pk': self.object.pk})
```

... throws an error because `self` is not defined.

**I know I can probably do this via sub-classing `get_success_url` or `get_absolute_url` but in the case I want to build a mixin/subclass of `UpdateView` is there a better way to keep it DRY?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the detail view is the default view you want to use for that Model Object you can add `get_absolute_url` function to your model https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/

```
class Company(models.Model):

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('company_detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

Comment: Sorry I don't follow you. Could you provide an example code snippet pls?

Comment: Thanks, you are no longer using a class based view in this example though...?

Comment: Yes this is still using the class based view. get_absolute_url is added to your Company model see docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/instances/#get-absolute-url. And the class based view will use this function to get url https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/views/generic/edit.py#L116

Comment: Ok, thanks but I don't see how this is `DRY`, it's just the same as subclassing `get_success_url` isn't it? E.g. if I was trying to create a subclass of this CBV it wouldn't allow me to pass variables.

Comment: It's more dry because you can reuse it on more places instead of the subclassing get_succes_url. One of the examples in the docs: `<a href="{{ object.get_absolute_url }}">{{ object.name }}</a>`

Comment: Thanks, I understand. The use case I am hoping for is to subclass the `updateview` so I can use it to return to a `detailview`, but if I define `company_detail` in `get_absolute_url` I can't see how to achieve that. E.g. other uses might be `person_detail`, `car_detail`, etc...

Comment: Are `person_detail`, `car_detail` used for different models? Then you create `get_absolute_url` for that models. If those are all used by the `Company` model and url is based on state of `Company` object you can inlcude that logic in the `get_absolute_url` and return the correct url for the state the model is in.

Comment: I tried your example and it just delivers `No URL to redirect to.  Either provide a url or define a get_absolute_url method on the Model.`?

Comment: Did you add the `get_absolute_url` function to your `Company` model that you use in your view?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205344/discussion-between-alias51-and-krukas).

Answer (score 0):

You should redefine **get_success_url()** method:

```
class CompanyUpdate(UpdateView):
    model = Company
    template_name = 'companies/company_update.html'
    fields = '__all__'

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse_lazy('company_detail', kwargs={'pk': self.object.pk})
```

so if its so common in your code and you want DRY you could create a mixin with the only (or a few) common methods/properties and mix it to what ever class you need

Comment: Thanks, ok to make it DRY how would I pass the `pk`? Isn't it better to do this without having to `subclass get_success_url`?

Comment: you need (some how) to know pk... I think you have 2 options: from self.object.pk or `signal` to the view via get or post params. For me the first option is much better...

Comment: Yes, that's the question! :)

Comment: class SuccessMixin():
        def get_success_url(self):
            return reverse_lazy('company_detail', kwargs={'pk': self.object.pk})
    
    class CompanyUpdate(SuccessMixin, UpdateView):
        pass

Comment: Won't this override `FormMixin` which means the form doesn't get validated?

Comment: Yes, but FormMixin contains default implementation of get_success_url - "check self.success_url or return the error". That's the point to overider the defauilt action...
Add mixin only if your are not happy with defaults...